# Would Oxygen Gas and Ozone be a pure substance together?

Tags: organic-chemistry, mixtures

If I have oxygen gas and ozone ($\ce{O2 + O3}$) together would it be considered a pure substance or a mixture?

And would pure substances always have the same molecular structure?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I am pretty new but I think it is not since the molecules have different quantities of oxygen.

Comment: Oxygen and ozone are two very different molecules. Ozone is a pungent gas. So you cannot call it a "pure substance". The problem with even calling pure dioxygen as pure oxygen is that it will be mixture of oxygen isotopes.

Comment: @M.Farooq And it also contains $\ce{O2-}$, $\ce{O2+}$, $\ce{O+}$, $\ce{O-}$ ions and monatomic oxygen. Not too much, but they are in thremodynamical equilibrium. But, I think, "pure substance" is a concept of the experimental chemistry, i.e. if there is thecompound on your desk, in a container, and not a theoretical thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ozone is highly reactive and unstable, while dioxygen is stable. There do not combine to form a compound. So, clearly it is a mixture.

To answer the second part of the question, "And would pure substances always have the same molecular structure?", first a [Wikipedia definition on substances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_substance#Definition), to quote:

> A chemical substance is a form of matter having constant chemical composition and characteristic properties.[1][2]...
> Chemical substances can be simple substances[4], chemical compounds, or alloys. Chemical elements may or may not be included in the definition, depending on expert viewpoint.[4]
> Chemical substances are often called 'pure' to set them apart from mixtures. A common example of a chemical substance is pure water...
> However, in practice, no substance is entirely pure, and chemical purity is specified according to the intended use of the chemical.

And further:

> A chemical substance may well be defined as "any material with a definite chemical composition" in an introductory general chemistry textbook.[5] According to this definition a chemical substance can either be a pure chemical element or a pure chemical compound. But, there are exceptions to this definition; a pure substance can also be defined as a form of matter that has both definite composition and distinct properties.[6] The chemical substance index published by CAS also includes several alloys of uncertain composition.[7] Non-stoichiometric compounds are a special case (in inorganic chemistry) that violates the law of constant composition, and for them, it is sometimes difficult to draw the line between a mixture and a compound, as in the case of palladium hydride. Broader definitions of chemicals or chemical substances can be found, for example: "the term 'chemical substance' means any organic or inorganic substance of a particular molecular identity, including – (i) any combination of such substances occurring in whole or in part as a result of a chemical reaction or occurring in nature".[8]

So, in a very elementary introduction to chemistry, the law of constant composition likely applies in the 'correct' answering of your question.

Note: In the context of advanced chemistry, there are also interesting examples of polymers of length 'n', again not precisely specified.